# how to access apn service

Tags: iphone, objective-c, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

i am new to the field, i dontkno0w what exactly is apn service in iphone. How can we access it. what code we have to write in server to connect with the device. please help me out
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest starting with the [Apple Push Notification Service](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ApplePushService/ApplePushService.html) Guide, which is a great overview (both on the client and server side).

Comment: Is the APN service  ,a in built feature of iphone?

Answer (score 0):

I would check out Urban Airship as a starting point:

http://www.urbanairship.com/

OR

http://www.xtify.com/

Comment: how to send notifications from our server?